# How to detect a variable change in React js/Solidity?

Tags: reactjs

I have a number variable in my react project that changes every couple of minutes.

I would like to make a popup on the screen that displays whether or not the number increased or decreased.

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to make a function that is always running and can detect when that number variable changes.

Comment: Please share your code showing what you have tried already

Comment: What changes the variable? There are many ways to do it. Pass it as a prop. Put it in context. Put it in state. Have it emit an event.

Comment: I figured it out using useEffect(). I simply set my changing variable to a const and passed it through in [] of useEffect().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using functional components you can use the `useEffect` hook,
like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
    //call your increment function here
},[someVariable]) //and in the array tag the state you want to watch for
```

the `useEffect` will cause a re-render when the state of 'someVariable' in the above example changes

you can see more about the hook in the react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html,

Comment: You may want to call the alert instead of the increment function inside the useEffect, (that could actually create and infinite loop).

Comment: Yes It could, thank you for correcting me @programandoconro , as long as the increment function updates the state for the target variable from any where it should work fine

Comment: @KirubelEneyew so I would have to make someVariable into a useState? the variable that's changing is a price feed that is read from a smart contract on ethereum. essentially the variable (price) changes every 3 minutes. 

What's the best way to use useState here?